# primefaces subtable styleClass

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable

I have a p:subtable inside a datatable.

In my datatable I'm using rowStyleClass attribute to define row's colour. All the row is painted but not the Subtable

What should I do to paint the subtable aswell.

Even if subtable would have a styleClass attribute, I could specify it again for it, but as far as I know, it doesn't exists

[image]

Comment: I suspect you'll find that the sub-table is inheriting a white background from somewhere.

If you can share a link where we can see this, someone can confirm for you.

Answer (score 0):

if subtable also has the class 'ui-datatable' try to style it

> .ui-datatable .ui-datatable {
>    background-color:none;
>   }

Comment: I solved it using background-color:transparent;

thanks a lot!